# How to implement plugin based architecture for the Electron windows application using Angular?

Tags: angular, plugins, electron, windows-installer

We have an angular based application, packaged using electron and generates an installer.Now we want to add pages dynamically in the form of plugins for the existing application.

For example:
We need to package new set of features as a plugin which should be add as an extension to the existing application.